# using bazel to build tensorflow, gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)

Tags: linux, tensorflow, gcc, bazel

I am trying to build tensorflow with bazel, but everytime I face:

```
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
```

The command I use is:

```
env BAZEL_LINKOPTS=-static-libstdc++:-static-libgcc BAZEL_LINKLIBS=-l%:libstdc++.a:-lm BAZEL_CXXOPTS="-std=c++17" bazel build -c opt --verbose_failures //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so  --action_env="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"  --local_ram_resources=HOST_RAM*.5 --local_cpu_resources=HOST_CPUS-1
```

I searched and add `local_ram_resources` and `local_cpu_resources` in the command to limit memory bazel used, but it seems not working.

the error log is:

```
ERROR: /public/home/users/ssctmf006t/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ssctmf006t/1a4bc2ee544cb9acb58fa5d1cf29da21/ext
ernal/llvm-project/llvm/BUILD:1854:11: C++ compilation of rule '@llvm-project//llvm:CodeGen' failed (Exit 4): gcc failed: error executing command   (cd /public/home/users/ssctmf006t/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ssctmf006t/1a4bc2ee544cb9acb58fa5d1cf29da21/exec
root/org_tensorflow && \  exec env - \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/public/software//compiler/gnu/7.2.0/lib:/public/software//compiler/gnu/7.2.0/lib64:
/public/software//compiler/gnu/7.2.0/mpfr/lib:/public/software//compiler/gnu/7.2.0/mpc/lib:/public/software//compiler/gnu/7.2.0/gmp/lib:/public/software//mpi/intelmpi/2017.4.239/intel64/lib:/public/software//compiler/intel/intel-compiler-2017.5.239/compiler/lib/intel64:/public/software//compiler/intel/intel-compiler-2017.5.239/mkl/lib/intel64:/public/software//compiler/intel/intel-compiler-2017.5.239/tbb/lib/intel64:/public/ibm/lsf10/10.1/linux3.10-glibc2.17-x86_64/lib \    PATH=/public/home/users/ssctmf006t/envs/dp-chang/tensorflow_venv/bin:/public/home/users/ssctmf006t/c
hangergo/software/bazel/bin:/public/home/users/ssctmf006t/bny/CALYPSO_x64/Tools/CALYPSO_ANALYSIS_KIT:/public/home/users/ssctmf006t/guofy/software/atomsk:/public/home/users/ssctmf006t/anaconda3/bin:/public/home/users/ssctmf006t/anaconda3/condabin:/public/home/users/ssctmf006t/guofy/software/vaspkit.1.2.4/bin:/public/home/users/ssctmf006t/zeng/software/cmake-installed/usr/local/bin:/public/home/users/ssctmf006t/zeng/software/deepmd-kit-1.2.2/bin:/public/home/users/ssctmf006t/envs/dp-compress/dp-compress/bin:/public/home/users/ssctmf006t/software/lammps-stable_29Oct2020/src:/public/software/compiler/gnu/7.2.0/bin:/public/home/users/nudt002/zeng/software/qe-6.5/PW/tools:/public/software/mpi/intelmpi/2017.4.239/intel64/bin:/public/software/compiler/intel/intel-compiler-2017.5.239/bin/intel64:/public/home/users/hpcplusadmin1/hpcplus-qjob-tool/LSF/sscmagic3:/public/home/users/nudt002/yaoyunpeng/Software/vmd-1.9.3/start/bin:/public/home/users/nudt002/software/grace/grace/bin:/public/home/users/app/tool/modules/bin:/public/ibm/lsf10/10.1/linux3.10-glibc2.17-x86_64/etc:/public/ibm/lsf10/10.1/linux3.10-glibc2.17-x86_64/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/public/home/users/ssctmf006t/perl5/bin:/opt/clusconf/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/openssh/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/public/home/users/ssctmf006t/.local/bin:/public/home/users/ssctmf006t/bin \    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
    PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/public/home/users/ssctmf006t/envs/dp-chang/tensorflow_venv/bin/python3 \
    PYTHON_LIB_PATH=/public/home/users/ssctmf006t/envs/dp-chang/tensorflow_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packa
ges \    TF2_BEHAVIOR=1 \
  /public/software/compiler/gnu/7.2.0/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set
-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections '-std=gnu++0x' -MD -MF bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/llvm/_objs/CodeGen/ReplaceWithVeclib.pic.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/llvm/_objs/CodeGen/ReplaceWithVeclib.pic.o' -fPIC -DLLVM_ENABLE_STATS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DLLVM_BUILD_GLOBAL_ISEL -iquoteexternal/llvm-project -iquotebazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/llvm-project -iquoteexternal/zlib -iquotebazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/zlib -isystem external/llvm-project/llvm/include -isystem bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/llvm/include -isystem external/zlib -isystem bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/zlib -isystem external/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/IR -isystem bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/IR -isystem external/llvm-project/llvm/lib/Target/AMDGPU -isystem bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/llvm/lib/Target/AMDGPU -w -DAUTOLOAD_DYNAMIC_KERNELS -msse4.2 -mavx -mavx2 -mfma '-std=c++14' -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' -c external/llvm-project/llvm/lib/CodeGen/ReplaceWithVeclib.cpp -o bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/llvm/_objs/CodeGen/ReplaceWithVeclib.pic.o)Execution platform: @local_execution_config_platform//:platform
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/> for instructions.
Target //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 539.406s, Critical Path: 186.23s
INFO: 1476 processes: 28 internal, 1448 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

[free -h on my machchine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ7py.png)

Comment: Maybe you hit out of memory error? Call bazel with a `-j 1` flag to reduce number of concurrent build jobs

Comment: Thank you , but i tried and failed again with basically the same errorl.log:

Comment: It's weird, it looks like you have.a plenty of memory. Maybe that it the real bug in the compiler. You can try with a `clang` (of course you have to install it first): add `CC=$(which clang)` env variable to the `bazel` invocation

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps try to install g++ if you haven't installed that compiler yet, but not so sure that can help.

Comment: Thank you，i got `g++ (GCC) 7.2.0 Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.` by `g++ --version` . Does that mean i have already had g++ installed so i do not have to install again?

Comment: It looks like Bazel uses `gcc` at `/public/software/compiler/gnu/7.2.0/bin/`, so check if `g++` is there as well.

Comment: Thank you, i checked by `which g++` and it turned located at `/public/software/compiler/gnu/7.2.0/bin/g++`, so maybe it is ok?

Comment: yep, but then I am not sure what is the error about.